# Make SQL Server LocalDb portable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, localdb

I'm setting up a new machine and to my surprise it is really difficult to get the localdb working on a new machine. Everything in my solution explorer populated, but nothing shows up in my (localdb) project after I fetch from source (using git).

What is the best way to get my localdb project from my old machine to this new one?

In an ideal world, what i'd like to do is have it set ups so then when some pulls the SSDT project down from our source they can hit deploy and completely populate the localdb project on their machine. Has anyone done this before, know how to do this?

--**Disclaimer**--

I feel like when talking about localdb it's important make some clarifications, because it seems that when other people post questions like this they get a lot of responses that apply to SQL Server databases.

> What a localdb project is:
>
> A localdb SQL Server project is a special server instance that runs only
> when its connected to and acts partly like a SQL Server and
> contains special instances of databases that only run when a
> connection is made to them.  A localdb can be used for certain types
> of production, but they are most often used as a means to test other
> databases.
>
> What a localdb project is not:
>
> A localdb project is NOT a SQL Server database.

I'm well aware that I could back up every DB in my project and manually recover them on the new machine, but that is not what I'm looking to do.

Comment: You'll need to clarify your question. I don't see any problem actually described in it.

Comment: @marc_s have to disagree most strongly.  It is an entirely different offering from MS that uses an offshoot of the same engine used in MSSQL Server, but it doesn't work in the same way, nor does it contain most of the features of SQL Server.

Comment: @mar_s I think you should you be more careful with your language.  SQL Sever <> SQL Server Express <> LocalDB.  I've developed in these for years and there are many differences (they are different applications after all), and though they may seem minor to you in my development they make very very big differences.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, thanks for calling it out.  I've edited the question, let me know if that makes it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by detaching and attaching process.

Step 1: Find the location of the localDB database.
Right click on the database name and select properties

[image]

From the **Data File** property, you can find the database current location.

Step 2: Detach the current database

```
EXEC sp_detach_db 'aspnet-IdentityApplication-E2BBF1E6-123-4567-8910-07BC0413419B', 'true';
```

Step 3: Copy and Paste the localDB to the different location (The location where you want to put the localDB database)

Step 4: Attach the database with the new location

```
CREATE DATABASE [aspnet-IdentityApplication-E2BBF1E6-123-4567-8910-07BC0413419B]  
    ON (FILENAME = 'D:\Test\aspnet-IdentityApplication-E2BBF1E6-123-4567-8910-07BC0413419B.mdf'),   
    (FILENAME = 'D:\Test\aspnet-IdentityApplication-E2BBF1E6-123-4567-8910-07BC0413419B_log.ldf')   
    FOR ATTACH;
```